# Shade smooth boolean problem

Tags: shaders

so today I am working on a shotgun model. I am trying to keep this model not too high poly, around 8-10k tris per each part of the model. And I have stumbled across a problem, which is my shading. I have been dealing with this problem for a very long time but I have no idea how to fix this. This is what I am talking about

[image]

As you see, you can notice the very ugly shading next to the hole, this is what the topo looks like.

[image]

I have no idea if this topology is good or bad ( if anybody can inform me about that it would be soo appreciated ) but I have a feeling it is because of the topology. If anyone can tell me how to resolve this problem it would be so great. ( I am trying not to use shade flat / bevel modifier / edge split modifier. )

EDIT: I've realized if I move some vertices near to the hole, it kinda fixes it but I don't know if this is good / bad practice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes your topology is bad, ngons create these artefacts, try this topology instead (create a hole, extrude inwards and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*):

[image]

Comment: Hello, so I am trying to achieve what you have showed me, but I have no idea on how to actually create those lines. I have tried CTRL + R (Shortcut in 2.79) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: once you've created a hole, select the square edge loop, then E and extrude inwards, then right click > LoopTools > Circle